# ClickOnce installation creating 2nd instance of application

Tags: clickonce

My company uses ClickOnce to install .NET applications for the users. The publish folder location and installation folder URL are being changed, so that the software installation package may exist on one server and no longer the other. When directing users to the new installation URL, it installs the application, but it creates a 2nd instance. It should replace the existing application, 'TestApplicationName'. Instead, it keeps 'TestApplicationName' and creates 'TestApplicationName - 1'.

This is a Windows application on .NET Framework 4. On .NET settings, on the security tab, 'Enable ClickOnce security settings' and 'This is a full trust application' are both checked. This is installed mostly on Windows 7 or Windows XP workstations.

The main troubleshooting steps that I have tried are:
re-signing the application
changing the platform and platform target between 'x86' and 'Any CPU'

Are there any ideas on how to use ClickOnce to replace the existing instance of an application, instead of creating a 2nd instance?